# How to avoid modal effects on background contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a modal which is popped up while clicking on a button. my problem is that ,when modal pops up , the background contents gets a bit spread, and sometimes they re scrolled down automatically . I have searched a lot to resolve this problem but i am unable to find the solution on it.So, please can anyone tell me where i am making mistake and how to overcome it?

this is  my sample modal code:

```
                              <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal reg_modal " id="regestration" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"   >
    <div class="modal-dialog" id="reg_outer_div" data-backdrop="true" >
      <div class="modal-content " style="background: white;width:700px;">
        <div class="modal-header" id ="reg_modal_header" style="">
          <button type="button" class="close reg" id ="reg_close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" align="center" style="color:white;" id="reg_log_modal_header_text">   </h4>
        </div><!--/header-->
         <div class="modal-body" style="background: white;" id="regmodal_body">


          </div><!-- /end modal body-->
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: Can you create jsFiddle to reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript file, add preventDefault() to the button to prevent page scroll when you click the button.

```
$(".button").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
}
```